# Keeping Transparency and White color in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]First off I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6 and I have an image that has a white stroke and a transparent background. Whenever I try to use image trace a white background fills up the transparent areas and using the ignore white setting removes all the white from my image which I dont want to happen. Anybody know how I can keep my transparent background, and my white colors in my logo while using image trace?

Comment: place an image in question here, plz.

Comment: unfortunately I cant, image is for work purposes and cant have any chance of it being copied. But its just an image with full color and a white stroke, transparent background.

Comment: @so, change the image to something else leaving the key points relevant to question.... otherwise, it is a little bit obscure question

Comment: Picture added, represents the basic principles I am trying to keep. I have a white stroke that I need on there, and I see "ignore white" is a big fix for most people. But in this case I need the white but also I need the transparency

Comment: is your picture of PNG format?

Comment: No it is a psd file from photoshop

Comment: if you want a white outline out of the symbol I suggest to create a white stroke on the outermost object after you use expand command (dont forget to delete the lowermost white background layer)

Comment: Fill background with red then trace, and delete red? Oh and I do hope that's just a mockup and not the thing you want to trace.

Comment: @joojaa I'd suggest to convert your comment to the answer - it is a great solution +1

Comment: Please tell me that circle isn't the image you are trying to trace. Please! :)

Answer (score 2):

Fill the background with a color your image does not use, like red, lime green or pink. Then trace as normal. Expand, then just select the background color with the magic wand tool and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>.

[image: image trace and result]

**Image 1**: Image, trace and result after magick wand

Comment: I think it is easy as just genius... +1

Answer (score 1):

- Trace your image - without being concerned over the white stroke.
- Expand the trace
- Add a white stroke to the resulting Group via the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]

Comment: This is not as bad advice as it sounds initially. It ensures that the outline is uniform and result is tidier. I would do this to even the black line for same reason.